# how ot proof 10%Z < Int.max_unsigned in Coq and the Int type from Compcert

Tags: coq, compcert

I want to proof a Z type value less than Int.max_unsigned.

Lemma test: 10%Z < Int.max_unsigned.
Proof.
??
How to prove the above test lemma?

Answer (score 5):

CompCert's `Int.max_unsigned` is defined in terms of a lot of other concepts like `Int.modulus`, `Int.wordsize`, and the `two_power_nat` function for calculating some `n` to the power of 2. It's instructive to understand how things are organized by unfolding each of these definitions one by one and observing what happens:

```
unfold Int.max_unsigned.
(* 10 < Int.modulus - 1 *)
unfold Int.modulus.
(* 10 < two_power_nat Int.wordsize - 1 *)
unfold Int.wordsize.
(* 10 < two_power_nat Wordsize_32.wordsize - 1 *)
```

But this gets boring. A simpler proof is to use the `compute` tactic to evaluate `Int.max_unsigned` and the comparison against 10:

```
Lemma test: 10%Z < Int.max_unsigned.
Proof.
  compute.
  (* The goal is now simply [Lt = Lt]. *)
  auto.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

These simple theorems can be proved by the `auto` tactic. Example:

```
Require Import ZArith.

Open Scope Z_scope.

Lemma test: 10 < 111.
Proof.
  auto with zarith.
Qed.
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the OP's case because `Int.max_unsigned` from the CompCert library is not a constant like `111` is. See my answer.

Comment: Right, need to do a `compute; reflexivity`. Was not aware of the complication behind `Int.max_unsigned`, thanks.